# neo4j: shortest path with minimal relationship property variance

Tags: neo4j, cypher, shortest-path

I created the following graph to model a transit network, where stops are connected to other stops via service nodes (service nodes define specific days of service). The relationships have distinct types and properties. Specifically GOES_TO relationships have an *id* property which identifies a trip (e.g. bus) travelling between the stops.

[image: neo4j graph model]

I wish to find the shortest path with the minimum number of distinct ***id*** values among all :GOES_TO relationships on the path.

In the case above, the shortest path should be:

(A)-[:USES]-(1:Service)-[:GOES_TO {id:7}]->(B)-[:USES]-(2:Service)-[:GOES_TO {id:7}]->(D)

This path uses a single id:7 to get from A to D.

Note that the condition applies only for :GOES_TO relationships. :USES relationships do not have and *id* property at all.

I have tried several approaches but cannot seem to get this seemingly simple problem resolved with cypher.

Comment: Did you solved your problem? Can you describe, How did you solved?

Answer (score 1):

Cypher can't do weighted shortest paths efficiently yet (hopefully soon!), but a workaround is to use reduce to aggregate over the path--the caveat being that it will need to look at all of the paths. Maybe something like this:

```
MATCH p=(a:Stop)-[*]->(d:Stop)
WHERE a.name='A' and d.name='D'
RETURN p, 
  length(reduce(acc=[], r in rels(p)| acc + 
  case 
    when type(r) = "GOES_TO" 
     and NOT r.id IN acc 
    then r.id 
    else [] 
  end)) as distinctIds
ORDER BY distinctIds ASC;
```

If it's not fast enough for you, you can get this to work pretty easily with the dijskstra's algorithm in an unmanaged extension on the server via the graphalgo package (or in embedded).

Comment: thanks for your answer, however I've tried this with my graph and it doesn't work. The query executes for about a minute and then fails with "Unknown Error".

Apparently Cypher isn't the way to go here. How would I go about doing this with graphalgo in java? Any useful resource/examples I can use?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you change the relationship type/depth to `-[:USES|GOES_TO*1..10]-`? If you're on 2.0-RC1 you can also match with properties, i.e. `(a:Stop {name:'A'})`. Possibly the execution engine does that for you already, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Yes, I am using node properties to match the initial nodes, and I am also using a depth limit on the relationship, but a depth of 10 is really small for this graph, as you can easily have a journey that spans over 25-50 stops, which makes for 50-100 relationships (stop-service-stop for each hop). 


I would like to follow up on the suggestion @WesFreeman made and write this in java. I looked into `org.neo4j.graphalgo.GraphAlgoFactory` but could find how to limit dijkstra by number of distinct `:GOES_TO.id` values. I'd really appreciate some sample java code.